# When is $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a-bx^n-x^2}}$ solvable in terms of elementary functions and why?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals, elementary-functions

The integral in the question appears in the solution to the orbit of a particle subjected to a central force. It is written in Goldstein's Classical mechanics that the solution is possible in terms of circular trigonometric functions without providing any reason. The wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_solutions_of_classical_central-force_problems refers to Whittaker which says that the expression under the square root must be quadratic at most.
I don't understand why it should be quadratic at most, i.e., why other values of n would make the integral stop having solutions with elementary functions only, what's the guarantee that no other integral value of n is possible?

Any help/reference will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the theory of [hyperelliptic integrals](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Hyper-elliptic_integral)

Answer (score 1):

As for as I know, the only values of $n$ for which we have closed form expressions are
$$\left\{\color{red}{-2},-1,\color{red}{0},\frac{1}{2},\color{red}{1},\frac{3}{2},\color{red}{2},3,4\right\}$$

Only the "red" ones leads to elementary functions; the other ones lead to very complex elliptic integrals of the first, second and third kinds (complete and incomplete).

For the other values, have a look at the link provided by @Jean-Marie.

Comment: Why do the red ones are the *only* the possible values which gives solutions in terms of elementary functions?